# InputAccessoryView doesn't show in SubViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9, inputaccessoryview

When i tried to use InputAccessoryView in normal ViewController it works perfectly. But when i try to use it in Sub ViewController, it won't show anymore.

Does anyone here face with it before?

`class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let myViewController = MyViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 200.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 200.0)
        self.addChildViewController(self.myViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(self.myViewController.view)
        myViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
}

class MyViewController: UIInputViewController {
    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        let view = UIView()
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return view
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .green
    }
}`

Comment: Please read https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html. Your custom container implementation is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it's still not showing even i tried to add the SubViewController correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an controller as subview should be like this :

```
        self.addChildViewController(self.myViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(self.myViewController.view)
        self.myViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Comment: Hi Rathish. Thanks for your suggestion. But even after implementing like this it still wouldn't show `inputAccessoryView`.